# Eclipse 3.4+ - No more notifying a breakpoint in taskbar

Tags: eclipse, debugging, taskbar, notifications

This question may sound silly, but I was wondering if someone ever had that problem too.
I was using Eclipse 3.2 to develop, earlier. Recently I changed to Eclipse 3.4 (ganymede), and I have a problem, concerning debugging.
Before, whenever the debugger was hitting a breakpoint, Eclipse would blink in the windows taskbar, to notify about it. But since switching to 3.4, it doesn't "blink" anymore, so, to debug a Swing application, it can easily get annoying, because you don't see directly when you entered a breakpoint.

In other informations, I'm using Eclipse 3.4 over the previous workspace, so I thought it might be a problem, with using the previous settings, but after trying on a brand new workspace, I encountered the same issue. I tried to search about it in the Eclipse community, but nothing like this so far.

Has anyone ever had that problem ? And if yes, is there a way to make it work ?

---

**Edit:** For information, updating to Eclipse 3.5 (galileo) didn't solve the issue, so I'm guessing it's not linked to only the previous update. Something probably changed since version 3.2, which is now preventing the usual "blinking" behavior. I can't figure out what, though.

Answer (score 1):

Mine will blink for me. I have 3.4.1. I did find a preference option under Run/Debug. The second check box says "Activate the workbench when a breakpoint is hit". I thought this was automatically selected on mine. If I deselect it, I don't get the blink. Check to see if that option is selected for you.

I also noticed that if Eclipse is not behind something else (like on a dual monitor, perhaps), the focus will just switch to Eclipse with no blink. If you're clicking around on your UI, you may not notice the focus switch.

Comment: I tried with checking/unchecking this option, but it didn't improve, unfortunately.
Fact that you have same version means that obviously I have to have something else on my side, and it's not related to the version...

Besides, I work on one monitor, and since it's a UI i'm launching, Eclipse is behind it, and won't blink, no matter if I make an action on the UI during or not. It does switch to the debug perspective (as expected from options), so title of the tab is updated, but nothing else.

Thanks for your answer anyway ;)

Comment: Interesting. This may not help, but it's a simple thing you can try: Add the -clean argument to your Eclipse shortcut. It clears some cached items and tends to help with other obscure Eclipse problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Eclipse which does the blinking but Windows. This usually happens when the application just opened a dialog and Windows didn't bring it to the front because you were busy elsewhere.

So the most simple way to get this behavior back is to enable the "This behavior is connected to the Debug Perspective. Do you want to switch now?"-dialog in the preferences.

Comment: Windows is, but Eclipse triggers it, on the base, at least it looked like that earlier.
About the simple fix, this would work only on the first breakpoint, but once switched to the debug perspective, it wouldn't notify anymore.